# Android - app icon for debug and release mode

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to set separate icons for application if we set android:debuggable=true in manifest and if we set android:debuggable=false like in iOS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide different Android app icons for different gradle buildTypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875948/how-to-provide-different-android-app-icons-for-different-gradle-buildtypes)

Comment: @longilong This question was asked before the thread you have provided.

Comment: true, but linked answer has a more clarified solution, and it was my first flag. sorry :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know app icons are only dependent on the drawables folder they are in, and there is [no folder qualifiers for -debug](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) and there's no way for you to alter the icon based on manifest changes

Comment: Whereas it is true that there are no folder qualifiers for debug, this can actually be achieved using flavors.

Comment: Check this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875948/how-to-provide-different-android-app-icons-for-different-gradle-buildtypes

Comment: See also here: https://peirr.com/random-android-gradle-tip-different-icon-per-buildtype/

Answer (score 26):

I'm a bit late the party, but anyway. At the moment I'm posting this in '16, you actually can have different launch icon set simply putting them to respective directories, not sure how it was back in '13 though. To achieve that you need to create **debug/res** directories under **app/src** and place your mipmap or drawable directories there. 
So you'll have **app/src/main/res/** and **app/src/debug/res/** paths. Android will have higher priority for build-related resource directory - to **main** directory. Place your debug and release resources to the appropriate paths and you'll have what you want. Do all of above considering you have to use Gradle build system.

Here you can read more about stuff like that: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging

Comment: This worked for me too: http://peirr.com/random-android-gradle-tip-different-icon-per-buildtype/

Comment: This works in 2022

Answer (score 7):

a bit late (actually about 8 years), but while I was browsing [DuckDuckGo's Android source code](https://github.com/duckduckgo/Android) today, I found out that they do it this way:

in your `app/build.gradle` ([DuckDuckGo's `app/build.gradle`](https://github.com/duckduckgo/Android/blob/develop/app/build.gradle))

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_blue",
                    appIconRound: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_blue_round"
            ]
        }
        release {
           ...
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_red",
                    appIconRound: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_red_round"
            ]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

and in your `AndroidManifest.xml` just use ([DuckDuckGo's `AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/duckduckgo/Android/blob/develop/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml))

```
<application
     ...
     android:icon="${appIcon}"
     android:roundIcon="${appIconRound}"
     ...
/>
   ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit late but I'll leave my solution for who is looking for the same answer.

On the **build.gradle** where the **buildTypes** are defined, I added a suffix for my debug_test build type to have a different apk installed on my device.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
    }
    debug_test {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        ...
    }
}
```

After that, go to File > New > Android Resource Directory and create a new mipmap resource directory for your debug_test build type (as you can see on Source set):

[image: Create new Resource directory]

I've created the mipmap folder because it's the folder for placing your app/launcher icons in only. All the other images should be placed in the drawable folders.

Add the ic_launcher icon to the folder created (app > src > res > mipmap > ic_launcher.png).

[image]

Now, just reference your icon on your AndroidManifest as below:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...
</application>
```

And the magic is done!

Comment: my icons shows like this `ic_launcher.png (hdpi,debug)`

Answer (score 1):

You need gradle and build flavors to do this. Then you can have different resource folders for the different flavors.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors

Comment: Debug and release build types are exposed for each flavor, so really this is not what the asker is looking for.  You are correct that you can change the icon per build flavor, but each flavor typically has a signed and unsigned APK, and it'd be nice if you could tweak the icon for those as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question - but if anyone else searches for this...

You can do this by creating a debug manifest (src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml) and updating its properties.

See: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Markers

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without fiddling `gradle`:

create a folder `debug` under `module_name/src`
then under `debug` create folder `res/drawable` or `res/mipmap` and put your debug icon there.

When you finished the above there won't be an extra "res" folder for the debug resources, but you'll see the "debug" annotation alongside your resources, like this:

[image]

(the second `ic_launcher.xml` is placed under `src/debug/res/mipmap` and it uses an adaptive background in `src/debug/res/drawable`)

Thus when the build variant is selected to debug, you'll see the icon is the debug icon you provided and when the build variant is set to release, you'll have the release icon.

Proved and used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas the response by Alex is fine in case flavors are not in use, for getting different icons while using different flavors with multiple dimensions, such as:

```
flavorDimensions "color", "size"
productFlavors {
    black {
        dimension "color"
    }
    white {
        dimension "color"
    }

    big {
        dimension "size"
    }
    small {
        dimension "size"
    }
}
```

This can be achieved as:

First, put the debug resources in separate folders, such as:

```
src/blackDebug/res
src/whiteDebug/res
```

Second, put the key with multiple flavor dimensions is that the sourceset name must contain all the possible flavor combinations, even if some of these dimensions do not affect the icon.

```
sourceSets {
    // Override the icons in debug mode
    blackBigDebug.res.srcDir 'src/blackDebug/res'
    blackSmallDebug.res.srcDir 'src/blackDebug/res'
    whiteBigDebug.res.srcDir 'src/whiteDebug/res'
    whiteSamllDebug.res.srcDir 'src/whiteDebug/res'
}
```

Just to make it clear, the following **will not work** when multiple dimensions are in use:

```
sourceSets {
    // Override the icons in debug mode
    blackDebug.res.srcDir 'src/blackDebug/res'
    whiteDebug.res.srcDir 'src/whiteDebug/res'
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try having two different app icons in your drawable folder - namely:

1. drawable/app_icon_release
2. drawable/app_icon_debug

When setting debug mode to true:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<manifest>
        <application 
            android:debuggable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_debug"
            android:label="Your App Name" >

        </application>  
</manifest>
</android>
```

Otherwise, when debug mode to false:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<manifest>
        <application 
            android:debuggable="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_release"
            android:label="Your App Name" >

        </application>  
</manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: this means you have to set it manually every time! Try using dynamic solutions.