# How to build multiple apps from one project with different app name, icon, settings,

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Building iOS and Android apps with only one project is pretty awesome. But is it also possible to build multiple apps with different names, icons, etc.

**This could be very helpful if you build apps with the same layout and maybe 95% same of the functions/code/algorithms:**

- different target-groups (recipes app for fitness, vegans, veggies, eco,...)
- different sports (news for football, basketball, tennis ...)
- different customers (business app for customer A, B and C)
- ...

**Things, which could be different per app:**

- App name
- App icons
- SplashScreen
- Design
- Settings (API URL, ...)
- Some code (default function/components maybe could get overwritten by app-based custom files)

Maybe it would be the perfect solution if you have a directory ***flavors*** where you can put all the files which you want to use to overwrite the default code-base.

Somebody here who released something similar or any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

Comment: How to overwrite iOS functions with Android flavors? .....

Comment: You should ask separate questions as IOS and Android are highly unlikely to have the same solution. My comment was obviously related to Android only.

Comment: For the app name, icon, etc. maybe there are different solutions for iOS and Android but I think for the code part it's not different.. We are talking about RN. The code I am talking about is not native..

Comment: Please take a look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875948/how-to-provide-different-android-app-icons-for-different-gradle-buildtypes

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem I have been solving in my projects last days. And I think I have some good (not perfect) solution so far.

**Idea.** We don`t have any built-in functions to help us handle this case, so we can use some external manipulation that can do the job. What we need is just multiple Android and iOS projects and single JS code base.

**Implementation.** I`ve come to this project structure:

- ios
- android
- manager
- src

`ios` and `android` folders is well known to you, they are native project folders.

`src` is a folder with JS code, you can organize it whatever you want

`manager` is most interesting one. Here we can store multiple native project files. We can have multiple native project folders in it, for example `app1-android` `app1-ios` `app2-android` `app2-ios`. And when we want to work on `app1` we just copy `app1-ios` and `app1-android` to our root `ios` and `android` folders, so the actual project is `app1`. When we are done with `app1` we can save `android` and `ios` folders to our `manager` and then just copy `app2-ios` and `app2-android` to root `ios` and `android`. And we are all good to develop our `app2`.

We can do it manually. But we are developers and we can make it much easier. I`ve written a PHP script that makes it as easy as `php save.php -a app1` and `php set.php -a app1` to copy from `manager` to root and backwards. Moreover, it takes care of not copying some unimportant staff (pods folder in ios, build in android etc.) and running `pod install` to ensure we have all pod in actual project.

I stick to one `package.json` file to have all npm modules installed once, so I don`t have to run `npm install` after each project switch.

Afterall, we can have as much projects as we wish in one repo, we can customize each one independently.

**PS** If you want me to share my scripts I`ll do it as fast as I can (need some time to prepare it for github and to write some more detailed instructions), just let me know.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but differently out of the box thinking... will try it. thanks.

Comment: Hey @Roman, can you please share the scripts ?

Comment: yep, could you please share your scripts?

Comment: @Roman, can you suggest me what other changes I need to do it android folder. like package name at what places and all.

Answer (score 3):

I did this for about 100 different native apps per platform (iOS/Android), sharing the same code base. I manage this setup for about 2 years now and I am still happy with it.

**Here is the iOS part:**

I use targets with different `plist`/`pch` files.

[image]

Save files that shuld differ per app in a separate directories, named by the app name. Check the corresponding target, if adding the file to the project:

[image]

By using the same filename you can "override" the file for different targets.

**The Android part:**

I use one gradle module for the common part and one module per app for the customizing. I also use gradle variables for common values definitions (`minSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion` etc.). Only the following settings differs per app: `applicationId`, `versionCode`, `versionName`. Here is an example file for a custom app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 28
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs rootProject.ext.signingConfigs

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':apps:common')
}
```

You can override the resources (app icon, images, strings etc.) in the corresponding `res` folder of an app module (use the same filename for the same resource).

Don't forget to include all your modules in the `settings.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple targets.

You can create target by below steps :

Go to project navigator -> Right Click on your app name under target -> Select Duplicate -> from popup select `Duplicate only` .

And you will find duplicate target. Now you can take another or extra `app icon` and `launch image` in your assets and for that target you can set it.

Refer below screenshots for better understanding!

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, select newly maded target and make changes by selecting it from `general` tab.

You can refer [this great tutorial by Appcoda!](https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/)

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar to what you want do, but on a much more limited range. We have various builds of our app, each with a name, logo, design, API URL...

It's only built for android, so it's essentially a few **flavors** as mentioned in the comments above. (I don't know what the equivalent system is for iOS)

But we also use https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config that provides a way to share these specific variables/settings between both the native (android and iOS) and javascript code. All you need is setup a `.env.myversion` file which contains the settings you need, something like:

`API_URL=https://my.server.com/
LOGO_FILE=/path/to/the/right/logo
COLORSET=shades_of_blue`

The correct file is pulled in at build-time so your app has the correct version of each setting and you can then call these variables from within your code, and branch based on what version you're using. The benefit is that it works everywhere. The downside to this is that you might be shipping some extra stuff with your apps if you have all this in the JS layer rather than defining it in the build system with flavors. I guess it's a tradeoff between convenience and performance/efficiency that you need to decide on based on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you can simply duplicate your Target and create a new one with a new plist which means you can change the app name, icon, splash bundle and other settings as required.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode you can Make different build confiugrations for different-different apps in single project(means Dev,alpha,beta,Prod,Debug,Release),With the help of this solution you are able to change AppName,AppIcon,BundleId,URLs,SplashScreen etc for different builds.

Answer (score 0):

I created a website, where users can specify their content, icons, name and package name, and many other options like including advertisement SDK in app. After small payment, user can get created APK with certificate or sign app manually. Generation of apk takes a few seconds. APK is ready to upload to PlayStore. This is project was with high price, but my customer is happy.

How it done?

1. Create some templates for code. You can buy it on some sites.
2. Split optional code in separate files
3. If you can't splite code in separate file (for AndroidManifest.xml, for example), you can include comment with some keys (instructions for post-processing)
4. Generate icons from user content/specified icons.
5. On user request, just copy all selected files in same directory, with simple text processor remove unnecessary code (use comments from step 3), complile it, ship APK to user.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two different options:

#### Option 1: OS Builds/android flavours:

Using iOS **Builds** and/or android **flavours** have some disadvantages in a react-native project:

1. React-native link only links the first target on Xcode.  You’ll have to manually link libraries for further targets. However in react-native 0.60+ there is auto-linking, and this could be fixed with a [little tweak](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/41#issuecomment-538007302) to the podfile
2. React-native run-android may fail to launch the app if the app id differs from the package id.
3. Might be complex overtime to maintain a single native project with all the different builds/flavours and all the assets and resources that are included in a single project.
4. Requires some extra knowledge with xcode and android studio/gradel.

#### Option 2: Natives approach (which I personally prefer)

Based on the answer of [Roman Osypov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47422314/833031), I have came up with this approach with an implementation.

Currently each react-native project has two native folders, `ios` and `android`, each one represents the native project of the platform.

Lets assume we have two different bundles/apps with the same code base but different resources/assets etc..

`CabApp` `TaxiApp`

The main idea is to swap but keep in sync the root ios and android folders with their "natives" source.

1. create a folder in the root of the project called `natives`
2. copy the current ios and android folder of the main project to the
   `natives` folder, lets assume it's `CabApp`, and rename those folder
   into the following: `CabApp-ios` `CabApp-android`
3. do the same for TaxiApp, but remember to change the bundleId, the
   identifiers, assets etc.. of the native projects
4. delete `ios` and `android` main folders in the root of the project
   and add them the `.gitignore`
5. install the following dev dependencies `yarn add -D rimraf sync-directory ttab`
6. now the first time the project is pulled you need to set your "app"
   for example if you want to work on `TaxiApp` you can execute the
   following:  `yarn ios-TaxApp` which you can define in the scripts in
   the package.json

```
yarn rimraf ios && yarn rimraf android && yarn syncdir natives/TaxiApp-ios ios -c && yarn syncdir natives/TaxiApp-android android -c && cd ios && pod install && yarn
```

Basically this command deletes the root folders `ios` + `android` and sync the folders from the `natives` folders to the root ones.

7. The final step would be **syncing** back and **watching** the modifications from the "temp" ios and android folders back to the `natives` respective app-platform.
   now in your start script for ios for example, you can add the following script
   `yarn ios-TaxiApp` which you can define as:

```
yarn ttab 'yarn syncdir ios natives/TaxiApp-ios -w -c' & yarn ttab 'yarn syncdir android natives/TaxiApp-android -w -c' & yarn ttab 'yarn react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 11\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Roman for the answer. Here is the php script which might help others.

```
<?php

// Define the root and manager directories
$rootDir = __DIR__;
$managerDir = $rootDir . '/manager';

// Parse command line arguments
$options = getopt("a:");

// Check if the app argument is provided
if (!isset($options['a'])) {
    echo "Please provide the app name using the -a flag.\n";
    exit(1);
}

// Extract app name
$appName = $options['a'];

// Check if the app directories exist in manager
$appDirIOS = "$managerDir/$appName-ios";
$appDirAndroid = "$managerDir/$appName-android";

if (!file_exists($appDirIOS) || !file_exists($appDirAndroid)) {
    echo "App directories not found in the manager.\n";
    exit(1);
}

// Copy iOS files
copyDir("$appDirIOS/", "$rootDir/ios/");

// Copy Android files
copyDir("$appDirAndroid/", "$rootDir/android/");

// Function to recursively copy directories
function copyDir($source, $destination) {
    $dir = opendir($source);
    @mkdir($destination);

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
            if (is_dir($source . '/' . $file)) {
                copyDir($source . '/' . $file, $destination . '/' . $file);
            } else {
                copy($source . '/' . $file, $destination . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
}
```