# How to automatically use different set of application icons based on chosen buildType?

Tags: android, android-studio

Iam trying to automatically switch between two sets of app icons based on the buildTypes i defined here at build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationIdSuffix ".release"
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

    }
}
```

I have already looked at this post, however my files structure is different and the offered solution does not work for my case. 
[How to provide different Android app icons for different gradle buildTypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875948/how-to-provide-different-android-app-icons-for-different-gradle-buildtypes/22876224)

Here is my files structure where there are two sets of icons stored at res-debug and res-release. How can I automatically switch between the two?

```
\app\src\main:
├───assets
├───java
│   └───com
│       └───myproj
│           └───videoplayer
│               ├───dialog
│               ├───dto
│               ├───entity
│               └───utils
├───res-debug
│   ├───layout
│   ├───mipmap-hdpi
│   ├───mipmap-mdpi
│   ├───mipmap-xhdpi
│   ├───mipmap-xxhdpi
│   ├───mipmap-xxxhdpi
│   └───values
└───res-release
    ├───layout
    ├───mipmap-hdpi
    ├───mipmap-mdpi
    ├───mipmap-xhdpi
    ├───mipmap-xxhdpi
    ├───mipmap-xxxhdpi
    └───values
```

Comment: You should have `debug` and `release` folders at the same level as `main`.

Comment: but moving the two folders need update of parameters somewhere, right? please provide an answer with details

Answer (score 0):

The correct folder structure should be:

```
└─src                            
    ├─debug                      
    │  └─res                     
    │      ├─layout              
    │      ├─mipmap-*         
    │      └─values              
    ├─main                       
    │  ├─java                    
    │  │  └─com.any.package                    
    │  └─res                     
    │      ├─drawable            
    │      ├─layout              
    │      ├─mipmap-mdpi         
    │      ├─mipmap-xhdpi        
    │      ├─mipmap-xxhdpi       
    │      ├─mipmap-xxxhdpi      
    │      └─values              
    └─release
       └─res                     
           ├─layout              
           ├─mipmap-*         
           └─values
```

Comment: It should work by default, with no any additional actions. You might have flavors defined in build.gradle file, it may break default behavior.

Comment: Tried again. Did not work. Also your answer is not complete, you did not mention anything about setting icons debug!

Comment: The debug icons are the default - the ones in the main directory structure.

Comment: You may create `debug` same way as `release`. But I cant identify why it's not working for you without error message at least. If no error message, problem might be in `build.gradle` or files.

Comment: Error:(27) error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka ir.teleboard.device.release:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

Comment: `ic_launcher` file not found neither in `main` nor in current (`debbug` or `release`) `res\...` folder. It should located in `main` **OR** in `debug` **AND** `release` source sets.