# Can we merge two android source and use product flavors?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-productflavors, android-build-type

I have two android project with **same source code** only **app icon change** in both app. But i don't have use product flavor. now i need to **merge source code** and use **product flavor**. so it is possible?

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

Comment: Thank you @Jameido, But i don't find out my solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22876224/5251245), basically what you need to do is to create a folder structure that mirrors the main->res->mipmap structure replacing main with your flavour name like this:

```
-src
  -main
    -res
  -app_one
    -res
      -mimap-*
        -ic_launcher.png
  -app_two
    -res
      -mimap-*
        -ic_launcher.png
```

**EDIT**

After merging the source code of the 2 projects you need to create 2 different product flavours in your gradle configuration and use the manifest placeholders for things like the app name and package:

```
productFlavors {
        app_one {
            applicationId "xxx.yyy.zzz"
        }
        app_two {
            applicationId "aaa.bbb.ccc"
        }
    }
```

And in your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="${applicationId}">
```

If the code content is the same you shouldn't have any issue, just select the right buildVariant and keystore when preparing the release apk.

Comment: No no, you are not understand my question, i am saying that, i have two different app (different source code) that already published on PlayStore, and now that have lot of bug (same bug in both source code), so for resolve i required to solve bug in both source code and that wast of timing so i want to merge both source code and then want bug solving in it, now my question is if i am merge both code and creating both signed APK and upload it on PlayStore with new version of APK then it is possible ? or it will give me any error ?

Comment: Thank you @Jameido, i will try your answer.