# Different launcher app icon for multi build type in android application

Tags: android, android-build-type

```
buildTypes {              
        staging {            
        }
        release {            
        }
    }
```

I want different application launcher icon for staging apk.
So I placed launcher icons files in separate folder under...

src/staging/res/mipmap-mdpi

src/staging/res/mipmap-hdpi

etc...

So, now I have got two sets of launcher icons, one in src/main/res.. and another one in src/staging/res
but staging apk still picking launcher icons from src/main/res

May I know, why its happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244842/3395198

Comment: Are you sure that you have `staging` editions of *all* editions of your launcher icon? IOW, are you sure that your `etc.` is truly covering all of the resource sets? Particularly if you used the Image Asset Wizard, you will have stuff in `res/drawable/` and `res/drawable-v24/` as well.

Comment: yes all folders are being taken care of @CommonsWare

Comment: thanks @IntelliJAmiya ...thats one of the approach. But I am trying to figure out why my approach not working?