# is it possible change Application icon dynamically in android without update the application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to add different types of App icons and different App names dynamically based on different places for the same application without update!. Otherwise, I need to provide 3 different builds. I hope I am clear.

Comment: Icon is possible. Reddit app actually supports this. Name, not so sure. However, this question doesn't really fit here as it stands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to provide different Android app icons for different gradle buildTypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875948/how-to-provide-different-android-app-icons-for-different-gradle-buildtypes)

Comment: yup and  also am looking for change the "app Name" too.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file and add this code

```
<application 
  android:theme="@style/Theme.packagename"
  android:supportsRtl="true" 
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:label="@string/app_name" 
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_first"
  android:allowBackup="true">

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

...
</activity>

<!-- second icon -->
<activity-alias 
  android:name=".MainActivityAlias" 
  android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_p_foreground"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_second"
  android:enabled="false" 
  android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
  
    <intent-filter>
  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  
    </intent-filter>
  
  </activity-alias>
</application>
```

this is a function to change the first icon into the second icon

```
private void changeIconToSecond() {
        // disables the first icon
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, "com.radefffactory.appiconchange.MainActivity"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        // enables the second icon
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, "com.radefffactory.appiconchange.MainActivityAlias"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

To return to the first icon

```
private void changeIconTOFirst() {
        // disables the second icon
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, "com.radefffactory.appiconchange.MainActivity"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        // enables the first icon
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, "com.radefffactory.appiconchange.MainActivityAlias"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Elazar Halperin can we do it without restart app because when i changing app icon then its close then its open